# NameError: name '' is not defined - Passing function return as input to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameter-passing, nameerror

I am trying to figure out how to pass the results of a Function to the other function in the same script.  I have tested the **CreateDict** function and it works.  I am unable to use the results as the input for **CreateHumanUsrNameDict**  The Error I receive with the below is **CreateHumanUsrNameDict(UsrDict)** **NameError:** **name** **'UsrDict'** **is** **not** **defined**

```
import csv
def CreateDict(filename):
    UsrDict = {}
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=':')
        for row in readCSV:
            UsrDict[row[0]]=row[1]
        return UsrDict


def CreateHumanUsrNameDict(UsrDict):
    HumanUsrDict={}
    for k, v in HumanUsrDict.items():
        if v == len(4):
            HumanUsrDict[k:v]
        print(HumanUsrDict)

if __name__=='__main__':
    CreateDict('Book1.csv')
    CreateHumanUsrNameDict(UsrDict)
```

Comment: You need to create UsrDict variable: UsrDict = CreateDict('Book1.csv')

Comment: You seem to have a basic misunderstanding of how `return` works. It doesn't cause the returned variable to automatically become visible in the calling scope. You need to *do* something with the returned value (e.g. -- assign it to a variable). Your code simply discards that return value, hence `CreateDict('Book1.csv')` has absolutely no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the return value to the variable UsrDict when you call CreateDict. Try this:

```
import csv
def CreateDict(filename):
    UsrDict = {}
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=':')
        for row in readCSV:
            UsrDict[row[0]]=row[1]
        return UsrDict


def CreateHumanUsrNameDict(UsrDict):
    HumanUsrDict={}
    for k, v in HumanUsrDict.items():
        if v == len(4):
            HumanUsrDict[k:v]
        print(HumanUsrDict)

if __name__=='__main__':
    UsrDict = CreateDict('Book1.csv')
    CreateHumanUsrNameDict(UsrDict)
```

Comment: Oh.... Thank you. I really appreciated the quick response and showing of the code!